# Разворачивание фантомного комментария шевелит куски вопроса

Tags: дефект, дизайн, комментарии, уведомления

[При разворачивании комментария](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676090/178988), помимо [бага с фантомностью](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4222/178988), ещё и шевелятся правая граница уведомления у вопроса и карточка пользователя:

[When you expand a comment](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676090/178988), besides the [bug with comment fantomness](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4222/178988), the right border of question notification is moving together with user card:

[image: скринвидео]